# Rails & Postgres - Are queries with count columns really this complex?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, named-scope

I have the following models in my app (only showing the related scopes):

```
class Audition < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.with_new_applications
    columns = self.column_names.map{|c| "auditions.#{c}" }.join(', ')

    select(columns).joins(:applications).merge(Application.unreplied).group(columns)
  end
end

class Application < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.unreplied
    columns = Application.column_names.map{|c| "applications.#{c}" }.join(', ')

    select("#{columns}, count(messages.id) as message_count").
      joins('left outer join messages on messages.application_id = applications.id').
      group(columns).
      having('count(messages.id) = 0')
  end
end
```

Due to using postgreSQL it seems like the queries have been made unnecessarily complex when compared to MySQL due to the need to include all the columns for the count columns/grouping.

Am I missing something? It doesn't seem very "Rails-like" to me.

Could these queries be executed in a simpler manner?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think the query is more complex in PostgreSQL as in MySQL? ANSI-SQL is ANSI-SQL and works in both databases the same for a simple COUNT

Comment: @Frank Heikens: I think he means that in MySQL you can use hidden columns with a GROUP BY: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html but in PostgreSQL you have to list all the columns or else write the query in another way.

Comment: That's pretty much it, seems odd that with PostgreSQL you are forced to put in the columns manually with each query. Maybe I've just been spoiled by the ActiveRecord/ARel magic so that it appears odd when a seemingly simple task is made more complex.

Leaving that aside, on the Rails front is there anything I could have done differently to arrive at a more elegant solution?

Comment: That's the same with (almost) every other brand of database, MySQL is the exception. PostgreSQL version 9.1 (release somewhere in 2011) will have a functional dependency on primary keys for GROUP BY's. This will fix your problem, but you have to wait... http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2010/08/08/waiting-for-9-1-recognize-functional-dependency-on-primary-keys/

Comment: You might want to read this article about the problems with leaving out columns from the GROUP BY: http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html

Comment: I understand the reasons why PostgreSQL requires the columns. The question is more about the Rails side of things - It seems odd that such a common occurrence is not handled by the framework in any way and that there is not a more elegant solution that what I've hacked together in the original question.

Comment: Sounds like an opportunity to contribute to ActiveRecord's growth.

Comment: PostgreSQL used to require 'as' to alias columns, then it became implied. Now, when I forget a comma, instead of raising an error, my query runs with one missing column and one misnamed column :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could approach the problem from a completely different angle by using the ActiveRecord :counter_cache ? e.g.

```
belongs_to :application, :counter_cache => true
```

You could maybe have a short, simple and performant query this way.

Comment: That's a great suggestion, would make it much simpler. Cheers